# How to determine which method its overriding in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

In the following code, I'm confused as to how do you know its `onClick` method of `OnClickListener` its overriding ?

```
fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show()


        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnClickListener` only have the onClick method. Therefore Kotlin will use a lambda expression to simplify it. The normal code to the `OnClickListener` is as given below.

```
setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
})
```

But if you have more than one method, this won't be the case. For example `setOnQueryTextListener` on a SearchView you need to override the two functions separetely.

```
setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
    override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
})
```

You can find more about Lambda functions from this [doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html)

Comment: Also you can only simplify to a lambda on interfaces that are defined in Java, as all the Android framework classes are.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note is that lambda expression like this is only possible when the lambda takes one function. To see what this is just to pay attention when creating your lambda.

We see here that when we create the onClick its expected parameter is View.OnClickListener. So an OnClick with a receiver of View.
[image: Decalring onClickListener]
So we can give it that.
[image: OnClickListener]
As we can see it was expecting one interface wich has one function, OnClickListener. 
[image: SAM-Redundant]
We can simplify this due to the fact that we are only expecting one interface function on our receiver "view" so it is implicit.
[image: Simplified on click.]

As stated before, we can only have a lambda like this with a single function, so if we look into our onClickListener we can see a single interface which has a single method so the lambda is implicit:

[image: onClick]

Comment: Does it: means interface ?

Comment: No, it is the implicity name of a single parameter, check this out: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html?_ga=2.256457611.1413388231.1565120517-87732984.1554836457#it-implicit-name-of-a-single-parameter